# Contraction (grammar) in User Interface

Tags: grammar

Is it considered unprofessional to use contractions (doesn't instead of does not) in UI. Should I avoid contractions completely or are some ok and some not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on your target audience and the voice you are using.  You can be quite professional and yet use an informal voice.  Check out http://balsamiq.com/ for an example (great tool, BTW).

Contractions are part of informal communication.  If you need to remain formal, then do not use them.  Also understand that a seemingly easily missed contraction can change the meaning of a sentence.  In that case, you shouldn't use them.  Finally, if you are writing for an international audience (that uses English), it is probably a good idea to avoid them.

In all other cases, they work well.

Comment: And yes, I intentionally switched between using contractions and not.

Comment: Um, sorry, but contractions are not a purely American thing; not even close. Here's some interesting stats on the contraction "don't" between the British and Americans http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8380/do-americans-say-dont-as-often-as-the-british.  Also - contractions are found and used in just about EVERY language.

Comment: I'd vote your answer up because most of it is spot on, but the first sentence is so infuriatingly off base, I am very tempted to vote it down instead.

Comment: Removed poorly received and self deprecating humor at the beginning.

Comment: http://www.plainlanguage.gov/howto/guidelines/bigdoc/writeContract.cfm